# Orphan road segments in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, topology, road, connectivity-analysis

I am working with OSM road data for a developing nation. Included in the dataset are various small networks of roads that are orphans or islands i.e. not connected to the main road network.  For example, four islands / orphans are evident in the section of roads below.

[image]

My aim here is to have all the roads connected that I can run a Steiner analysis without getting errors from nodes that do not connect.

How can I get QGIS to select these so that I can either delete them or connect them to other sections of road network?

Comment: Basically you need to clean your network data. I'm more familiar with doing this and the questions already here related to doing it for [ArcGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92147/). You're going to want to look into topology and topology checks. Also dangles (rmdangle) and pseudo-nodes if you want to do Steiner and I'm remembering correctly. I list checks I use for network cleaning in my answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112911

Comment: Thanks for the input @Chris W.  I have made various attempts to snap, clean and break the data but still haven't quite got it right and many of the pseudo nodes still exist.  I will keep plugging away.....

Answer (score 1):

The solution I adopted to this followed on from another response from @Chris W at [How do you remove isolated roads from a bigger network?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92147/how-do-you-remove-isolated-roads-from-a-bigger-network/92235#92235) where he use a 'kludge' of a service area.  In my case, in QGIS I created a single central point to the network and use v.net alloc for a netwok allocation which (I think) found all connected roads.  I used this in the later analysis.  For the record, this was still full of pseudonodes even after snapping, breaking and bpol with v.clean.